# SSIS XPATH to Parse XML

Tags: xml, xpath, ssis

I've been working on doing an XPATH but can't get the path right.... I've seen several suggestions about using /* combinations -- but can't get any of them to work.

I'd really appreciate any hints on what I might try.  If I can figure out how to grab the pra_no element that would move me in the right direction.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-16"?>
<DataSet>
<xs:schema xmlns:msdata="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-msdata" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns="" id="NewDataSet"> 
<xs:element msdata:UseCurrentLocale="true" msdata:IsDataSet="true" name="NewDataSet"> 
<xs:complexType> 
<xs:choice maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="0"> -<xs:element name="Cust"> 
<xs:complexType> 
<xs:sequence> 
<xs:element name="pra_no" minOccurs="0" type="xs:string"/> 
<xs:element name="s50005" minOccurs="0" type="xs:int"/> 
</xs:sequence> 
</xs:complexType> 
</xs:element> 
</xs:choice> 
</xs:complexType> 
</xs:element> 
</xs:schema>
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about SSIS, but if you managed to define prefix to be used in your XPath (or if namespace prefixes are auto-resolved in SSIS), then you can use the following XPath :

```
//xs:element[@name='pra_no']
```

The XPath find `xs:element`, anywhere in the XML document, having `name` attribute value equals `"pra_no"`. Alternatively, if you can't use prefix, try the following instead :

```
//*[local-name()='element'][@name='pra_no']
```

Comment: I get no results with both of those, unfortunately.  I'll play with it a bit more today.